# Solve the system $a^3+b^3= 28$, $(a+2)(b+2)(a+b)= 60$

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

> Solve the system $a^3+b^3= 28$, $(a+2)(b+2)(a+b)= 60$,
>   where $a,b \in \mathbb{R} $.

**My try:**

If $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$(a+2)(b+2)(a+b)=3\times 4\times 5 \to a=1, \, b=3 $$

$$a^3+b^3=27+1 \to a=1, \, b=3$$

but $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is your question? Are $a,b$ integers?

Comment: can yo write some context to the Problem?

Comment: @DietrichBurde . no $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the second equation by 3 and add it to the first. Then
$$a^3+b^3+3(a+2)(b+2)(a+b)=208\\
a^3+b^3+3(ab+2a+2b+4)(a+b)=208\\
(a+b)^3+6(a+b)^2+12(a+b)=208$$
Let $a+b=x$. Then $x^3+6x^2+12x=208$. 
Since you already know one root, you're left with a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the equations in terms of $s=a+b, \,p=ab\,$ gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
    s^3 - 3 p s &= 28 \\
    (p+2s+4)s &= 60
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

Eliminating $p$ between the two equations results in a cubic in $s$: $s^3+6s^2+12s-208=0\,$. Trying out factors of $208=2^4 \cdot 13$ finds the root $s=4$, which then gives $p=3$ so $\,\{a,b\}=\{1,3\}\,$.

Factoring out $s-4$ leaves a quadratic $\,s^2 + 10 s + 52 = 0\,$ which gives a couple of complex roots $s=-5 \pm 3\sqrt{3} i$, each one corresponding to a pair of complex $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the equations are symmetric in $a$ and $b$ we obtain with $(a,b)=(1,3)$ also $(a,b)=(3,1)$ as a solution. Indeed, computing the resultant of the two polynomials we obtain
$$
(b-1)(b-3)(13b^4+130b^3+682b^2+2244b+3492)=0.
$$
The last term has no real solution. So we obtain the above real solutions.  However, we obtain $4$ new complex solutions.